# C# For Loop, While Loop, LastIndexOf, IndexOf, Why the last 2 are faster?

Tags: c#, performance, for-loop, arraylist, indexof

I have done some performance testing in C# on using the For Loop and the While Loop for an ArrayList to do comparison search.

It seems to be having quadratic time consumption.

However, if I use `LastIndexOf` or `IndexOf` to search through the list, it gains "faster than anticipated" speed.

Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: It would really help if you could show us your benchmarking code. It's hard to explain results without knowing what you're doing. Also, why are you using `ArrayList` instead of `List<T>`?

Comment: If you wrote your code in a way that has quadratic performance then it's your code that's badly written and thus it should not be surprising for `LastIndexOf`/`IndexOf` to be much faster. Also using `ArrayList` is only a good idea if you develop for .net 1.x (or need to inter operate with such code). On .net 2 and later there you have generic collections, in particular `List<T>` replaces `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
My workaround goes this way: Scanning of xmltext to find node, and find parent and child relationship within the node. The sequence is important, thats why i need to have loop within loop to search the last index of the parent. I will try List<T> for performance see what comes out. However, my question is, what is the reason behind for LastIndexOf/IndexOf to search the list faster than a for loop?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know *any* C# and yet I can put forward the likely answer.

Any programming language method are generally written in ways that take advantage of shortcuts made available by the processor that they run on - which your own written code will not (eg you'll have to declare local variables which will have to be kept on the stack, requiring slower lookup times, instead of just being a temporary register variable). Thus anything the language does natively will generally be quicker than your own code.

Comment: I downvoted your answer, because it is utter nonsense. .NET does not take shortcuts based on processor (as far as the BCL is concerned) and anything that the BCL does you can do just as fast (sort of, you do not have access to the private members of the class, but accessing those is not currently relevant). What I'm trying to say is that you can write exactly the same code that is in the BCL and it will be just as fast!

Comment: It most definitely does make sense. I had in mind compiler optimisations - which are done without ones own knowledge.

Comment: The same compiler optimization will be done on your code as well. You can make a 1:1 copy of the same code in the BCL and it will be just as fast. In that regards Microsoft is not doing any clever magic behind the scenes that would make their code much faster than yours. .NET is a level playing field so to speak. The only thing in question is whether Carnegeia is using an efficient algorithm for the task in hand, in this case Micrsoft seems to be using a better one. The answer (as per my answer to this post) lies within LastIndexOf/IndexOf implementation, which you can look with ILSpy.

Comment: yes, if your code is an exact copy... but in most cases it won't be. However - I'll also remind you that this is an answer based not on the specifics of C# - which I clearly pointed out I don't know - nor do I know about the internals of how it's compiled. My answer is generic, in that... in general - if the average developer hand-rolls their own code - it probably will not be as performant as the optimised algorithms written in the standard libraries.

Comment: In your answer, you said that programming language methods are written in ways that take advantage of shortcuts by the processor that they run on. That is the point I'm refuting - the BCL does not take shortcuts nor are there any special compiler optimizations. The last sentence in your final comment - that is true, standard libraries generally do use the most optimised algorithm for the task in hand and most developers wouldn't write code as good as that themselves. The problem is, your answer doesn't talk about that, instead it implies somehthing which isn't true.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me something new about the BCL. Interesting to know that not all languages can take advantage of better optimisation than their own code (or conversely that the compiler is smart enough to use the same kinds of optimisations in standard, end-user development as for its own internal base libraries).

Answer (score -1):

Use ILSpy and take a look at the internals of LastIndexOf/IndexOf methods. There lies your answer as to why they are faster.

I have a hunch that the List internally uses a B-tree or some other tree, which has a lookup of log(n). What you are doing with for/foreach is performing a linear lookup with some extra overhead. If you remember your maths class then you'd know that log(n) is flatter than a linear line, thus having faster lookup...

Comment: `List` does not use a B-tree or any other tree internally. Searching through a `List` is an O(n) operation.